# Failing to call action on the previously active item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In short, I have a list of items, one of which is set to `.active`:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

$("li:not(.active)").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active")
    .siblings("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sasy0faL/

When you click one of the items that is not `.active`, the code should change its status and remove the `.active` class from other items.

To reproduce the issue, you need to click one of the inactive items (for example the 2nd one), then try to click on the previously active item (the 1st one) to make it active again. It will fail to do so, even though it is not active at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to elements that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

So, As per current implementation event handler is only attached with element which does't have the `active` class.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or **manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).**

```
$('ul').on('click', "li:not(.active)", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active")
    .siblings("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

[image: jsFiddle]

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: While this works, you might like to add a quick explanation as it looks like it *should* have the same problem as the original

Comment: @freedomn-m, Hope this suffices

Comment: Thanks, @Satpal. This one worked. Thanks for the explanation too, because this will prevent me from future mistakes of this kind!

Answer (score 2):

Well that is because you have not attached event to active element(using `li:not(.active)`). modify your code to attach event to all li element and only add class active when element do not have it:

```
$("li").click(function() {
if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qx3Lnxcp/)**

Comment: Although, this one worked too, I think delegation is a more elegant way to solve this issue. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding click event handlers to all list items except first item. So that's why when you click on first item, nothing happens.

```js
var listItems = $('ul li');

listItems.click(function() {
    listItems.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This one is a good solution too, however it didn't help me understand what went wrong in my example.

Comment: @Deka87 `$("li:not(.active)")` problem exists here. This selection doesn't include first list item. So click event is being attached to all other items but not with the first one.